# REST API populate creator_id in serializer to use in permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How do I populate `creator_id` in the `Post` request, and use it in permissions? I have tried doing it in views and it worked to generate the `id` in the creator's column. But for the permissions, it didn't work, and so I wasn't allowed to delete my own note. Then I was told to move this action to `serializers.py`.
Currently what I have:

`Models.py`

```
class Note(models.Model):
    class NoteTypes(models.TextChoices):
        POST = "Post"
        IDEA = "Idea"

    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=NoteTypes.choices, default=NoteTypes.POST
    )
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created_date"]
```

`Views.py`

```
class NotesList(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        serializer = NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = NoteSerializer(data=request.data)
        request.data["creator"] = request.user.id   <------
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`Serializers.py`

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="creator.id")

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ["uuid","category", "creator", "content", "created_date", updated_date]
```

`Permissions.py`

```
    
    class IsCreatorOrReadOnly(BasePermissions):
        def has_object_permission(self, request,view,obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True

            return obj.creator.id == request.user.id
```

I've tried to populate the creator's `id` in the `creator` field in `views.py` and it works. i.e. `"creator": "2"`, however with this I wasn't able to delete or update the note. I'm currently trying to move this action to serializers.py` to auto-populate this field.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is make the `creator` field reference to a foreign key in the `user` model:

```py
# other imports .....
# import user model if it's not in the same app

class Note(models.Model):
    class NoteTypes(models.TextChoices):
        POST = "Post"
        IDEA = "Idea"

    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=NoteTypes.choices, default=NoteTypes.POST
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # new 
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created_date"]
```

Then in your `serializers.py`, I notice one field is not inside the `" "` . So fix it as shown below. Besides that, everything else looks good.

```py
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="creator.id")

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ["uuid", "category", "creator", "content", "created_date", "updated_date"]
```

Now we will bind each note to its creator in the `views.py` by overriding the `perform_create()` method, and also check for permissions:

```py
from rest_framework import generics

class NotesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsCreatorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

As for `permissions.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsCreatorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
        def has_object_permission(self, request,view,obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True

            return obj.creator == request.user #new
```

Comment: I like your response and i had something similar to this, however in the project im working on ive been told i cannot use foreign key in the creator field(it has to be charfield and id be using its index to identify creators) so this would be used in the permissions as well -> obj.creator_id == request.user_id. So my question is if theres a way without FK and use the index of the creator as an identifier.

Comment: Do you want the creator field to store the id of the one who created the note and then use that id in permissions, or do you want the index of the creator field (its id) to be used in the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

try to return this on your permission class:

```
return obj.creator == str(request.user.id)
```

Instead of this:

```
return obj.creator.id == request.user.id
```